# ie.maximize and ie.bring_to_front commands are not working in an application which has got lightbox opened by default on the Home page

Tags: watir

I am working on an application which has got light box on the Home page, I need to close the light box and navigate to the Home Page, I am closing the Light box with the script and navigating to the Home page.
I am trying to bring the application to front and maximize the window.
I am using commands "ie.bring_to_front" and "ie.maximize".

These commands work for an application which has not got light box on the Home page.

Is it due to the Light box which is present on the home or is it due to java script the page has got.

Please suggest

Thanks and Regards,
Ajazz.

Comment: Nobody can really answer that without examples of the page html (or a link to the page). I would suggest that you provide the watir code that isn't working, and which versions of ruby & watir.

Comment: We also need a better idea of what this 'light box' is, is it a special div within the browser, or a separate browser window, or what?   If there is a public URL that can be accessed where we can view this 'lightbox' that could also help immensely in terms of figuring out how to manipulate it, close it, etc.

Comment: three days and no response from @ajazz   must not need an answer very badly.

Comment: I tried the scenario with Watir 1.7.1, Ruby 192 and 187 versions.Iam working on an application which is hosted in my local machine.

Iam trying with the below code :

{
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir/ie'

iewin=Watir::IE.new

iewin.goto "http://xects.creative.ct.net/AP/OST/Home.aspx"


iewin.bring_to_front
iewin.maximize()
}

When I run the same code by changing the URL to google or some other site, these commands work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to assist you.

Without seeing the code that is actually running on that page, and with no indication of the failure mode beyond 'not working' (e.g. what actually happens, do you get an error message of any sort?) no description of the 'light box' application, not even a screenshot,  it's nearly impossible to know what is causing the code to fail.  ESPECIALLY since we know the code is not at fault since it works on other sites.

Please find a psychic who can read your mind and get the information needed to help you, since you seem to be incapable of providing it when requested

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put in to assist me on this. Due to some security reason I was unable to produce the code but not incapable. Next time I try to raise a question I will ensure that I produce the code if required.